# Error when converting between Mediastore Uri and DocumentFile Uri: "Failed to determine if is child of"

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is the scenario:

I'm writing an app which asks user to open a directory and the app is loading all images in the directory (and then doing basic operations like move or delete). Because `listFiles` is slow, I'm getting images using `MediaStore` API (querying on `_data` column taken from received `DocumentFile` `Uri`) and converting them when needed to `DocumentFile` as follows:

```kotlin
// Given MediaStore Uri:
val docUri = MediaStore.getDocumentUri(context, mediaUri)
return DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(context, docUri)
```

The problem is, *sometimes* I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to determine if primary:DirectoryA/image.jpg is child of primary:DirectoryB/image.jpg: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Missing file for primary:DirectoryB/image at /storage/emulated/0/DirectoryB
```

...when I try to get `DocumentFile` for some `image.jpg` in directory `DirectoryA` (first line). For some reason Android tries to check if `image.jpg` should be in different directory? (Perhaps images was there at some point?).

Btw, when I'm moving images I'm using `DocumentsContract.moveDocument`.

*App is Android 10+.

#### Update: How am I querying MediaStore:

```kotlin
context.contentResolver.query(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA),
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA + " like ? and " + MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA + " not like ?",
    arrayOf("$path/%", "$path/%/%"),
    null
)
```

This works on Android Q, with `targetSdkVersion 29`.

Comment: `(querying on _data column taken from received DocumentFile Uri) ` Please show how you do that. Under Android Q the .DATA column is not usable.

Comment: Still unclear what you use for $path and how you obtained that value from a DocumentFile uri.